# How to transform json tree recursively with jq?

Tags: json, recursion, tree, jq

I have the following JSON that I need to transform with jq. The main task is to leave only specified attributes in the tree. The number of levels in the tree may be different.

```
    {
    "metaModel": [ {
        "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
        "code": "code1",
        "default": "value1",
        "children": [ {
            "clazz": "AttributeClass2",
            "code": "code21",
            "default": "value21"
        },
        {
            "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
            "code": "code22",
            "default": "value22",
            "children": [ {
                "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
                "code": "code31",
                "default": "value31",
                "children": []
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "clazz": "AttributeClass2",
        "code": "code2",
        "default": "value2"
    }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to get the output like the following (leave only clazz, code, children)?

```
    {
        "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
        "code": "code1",
        "children": [ {
            "clazz": "AttributeClass2",
            "code": "code21"
        },
        {
            "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
            "code": "code22",
            "children": [ {
                "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
                "code": "code31",
                "children": []
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "clazz": "AttributeClass2",
        "code": "code2"
    }
```

'metaModel' may be left in the output too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `walk/1`:

```
.metaModel
| walk( if type == "object" and has("clazz")
        then {clazz, code} + (if .children then { children } else null end )
        else .
        end )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following recursive function seems to meet the requirements, or at least the filter `.metaModel | transform` transforms the sample input in accordance with the sample output:

```
def transform:
  if type == "object" and has("clazz")
  then  {clazz, code} + (if has("children") then {children: (.children|transform)} else null end)
  elif type == "array" then map(transform)
  else .
  end;
```

### Footnote

If you don't like the redundancy of the expression

```
{children: (.children|transform)}
```

you could write:

```
{children} | map_values(transform)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses [tostream](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostream), [setpath](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#setpath(PATHS;VALUE)) and [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce):

```
reduce (tostream|select(.[0][-1]|.=="clazz" or .=="code" or .=="children")) as [$p,$v] (
  {}; setpath($p;$v)
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZKxboMwEIZ3nuJkMYCURsXdiDJUmfsEyIMLVyWVU4h9MCTh2SnEUcCQkJYBdPf/9vdj3/ehaTRmZYoQUG5Io9yfDSpMKVgmryJ5icR5uV6zVMnjkUGu4VLlGfbFdqcyjT8sDEEaSPxi4VcCAg/gVK/AIBWStoFfrPwq9MKmgfY5ed2b7ZHkR7uZYjEk1@ZFsLwY2DuR3n2WhBsljYnYYuDpUsT26wgZfslSUadVUpWueIvrEueofLB@QubRWB3jW8fNUPfev7GjWTZ/yp5mf/z//8kxyfJ21zHOc981zCQcuXaqXuv7tnc91@cTxB9NEJ@bIG5v0FKFV/8C)

tostream converts your input to "streaming" [path,value] form:

```
[["metaModel",0,"children",0,"clazz"],"AttributeClass2"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",0,"code"],"code21"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",0,"default"],"value21"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",0,"default"]]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"children"],[]]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"clazz"],"AttributeClass1"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"code"],"code31"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"default"],"value31"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"default"]]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0]]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"clazz"],"AttributeClass1"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"code"],"code22"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"default"],"value22"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"default"]]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1]]
[["metaModel",0,"clazz"],"AttributeClass1"]
[["metaModel",0,"code"],"code1"]
[["metaModel",0,"default"],"value1"]
[["metaModel",0,"default"]]
[["metaModel",1,"clazz"],"AttributeClass2"]
[["metaModel",1,"code"],"code2"]
[["metaModel",1,"default"],"value2"]
[["metaModel",1,"default"]]
[["metaModel",1]]
[["metaModel"]]
```

select filters out all paths not ending in "clazz", "code" or "children":

```
[["metaModel",0,"children",0,"clazz"],"AttributeClass2"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",0,"code"],"code21"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"children"],[]]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"clazz"],"AttributeClass1"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"children",0,"code"],"code31"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"clazz"],"AttributeClass1"]
[["metaModel",0,"children",1,"code"],"code22"]
[["metaModel",0,"clazz"],"AttributeClass1"]
[["metaModel",0,"code"],"code1"]
[["metaModel",1,"clazz"],"AttributeClass2"]
[["metaModel",1,"code"],"code2"]
```

reduce and setpath reconstruct the final result:

```
{
  "metaModel": [
    {
      "children": [
        {
          "clazz": "AttributeClass2",
          "code": "code21"
        },
        {
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [],
              "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
              "code": "code31"
            }
          ],
          "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
          "code": "code22"
        }
      ],
      "clazz": "AttributeClass1",
      "code": "code1"
    },
    {
      "clazz": "AttributeClass2",
      "code": "code2"
    }
  ]
}
```